# Pass varargin inputs into sprintf

Tags: matlab, printf, variadic-functions

Is there a way to pass the inputted arguments in a function, `varargin`, into an `sprintf` command?

The problem is that sprint doesn't like cell inputs. I've tried using `varargin{:}` and the series of `mat2str(cell2mat(  )`

Ideally I want to have this in a loop

```
for k = varargin 
    filename = sprintf('%s.mat',i)
    more code......
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to print the names of the inputs, or what they contain? If the latter, do you want it to handle anything thrown at it or are we assuming there's some limit to what type of inputs this particular function takes?

Comment: The input will be strings, and I just want a way to pass these inputs into their own variable names. Also I noticed I switched the itterator from k to i in my example, they should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

To help people landing here by googling for the title:

You can pass `varargin` to `sprintf` this way:

```
sprintf(format, varargin{:})
```

Matlab will convert cell array to comma-separated values, like

```
sprintf(format, varargin{1}, varargin{2}, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, to be honest.  Try this:

```
for k = 1:length(varargin)
    filename = sprintf('%s.mat', varargin{k})
    more code......
end
```

This assumes that all inputs are strings.

Another related and quite useful function is `inputname` which you can use if you want to return the names of the variables passed in as arguments.

```
for k = 1:length(varargin)
    filename = sprintf('%s.mat', inputname(k))
    more code......
end
```

One thing to watch out for: `inputname` returns an empty string if an input is unnamed.